# My PHP variables aren't inserting into my MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

mysql_connect("10.246.16.129", "alanay_org", "SNIP")or die("Cannot Connect"); 
mysql_select_db("alanay_org")or die("cannot select DB");

INSERT INTO members ('id', 'username', 'password')
VALUES
(NULL, '$_POST[username]','$_POST[password]')";

?>
```

My code isn't inserting into my MySQL table, the rows go by id, username then password. I've checked and I haven't gotten anything wrong from the HTML register form. Please help.

Sorry, I'm really new to PHP. Give me a break.

EDIT:

This is the register.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/form/stylesheet.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <form action="/form/registered.php" method="post">
                <input class="username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
                <input class="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Register" />
            </form>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the registered.php

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("10.246.16.129","alanay_org","password","alanay_org");

$sql = "INSERT INTO members ('username', 'password') VALUES ('$_POST['username']','$_POST['password']')";

mysqli_query($con, $sql);
?>
```

What am I doing wrong? :(

Comment: 1, **Don't** use mysql*, 2. **Don't**  insert unsanitised user strings, 3 **Don't**  store plain text passwords, 4 - sorry this just sucks

Comment: Read the error message(s). That's not even close to being valid PHP and will fail to parse.

Comment: where is `mysql_query()`

Answer (score 2):

Your post variables have the wrong syntax. This:

```
$_POST[username]
```

should be:

```
$_POST['username']
```

Plus what @Dagon said.

Comment: plus missing semi colon, and much more problem

Comment: @Dagon Really, your style of response is better. A comment is more appropriate here, unless I was going to spell out the whole set of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("host","username","password","database_name");
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO members ('username', 'password') VALUES ($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
```

You don't need to put id if it is auto-increment.
This method is not secure from SQL injections. You can use prepared statements for security purposes.

Comment: Yeah... that wasn't it.

Comment: Did you try above code? I think `'$_POST['username']'` and `'$_POST['password']'` were causing problem. Fix them to `$_POST['username']` and `$_POST['password']`. **Code edited** and sorry about previous code. My eyes were being closed when I tried to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
mysql_connect("10.246.16.129", "alanay_org", "SNIP")or die("Cannot Connect"); 
mysql_select_db("alanay_org")or die("cannot select DB");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO members ('username', 'password') VALUES ('".$_POST['username']."','".$_POST['password']."')");
?>
```

If this doesn't work for you, your POST-variables are missing or empty.